# Prime number factorization

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a function to take a positive integer and a prime number as an input and return true if the prime factors of the given positive integer are **less than or equal** the given prime number.

Given prime number should be a prime factor of the given positive integer.

hasLessPrimeFactor(20,5) should return true because Prime Factors of a Number: 20 = 2 X 2 X 5

```
 Up to now I have completed 3 test cases out of 4 test cases
```

1. The return type should be a string.
2. hasLessPrimeFactor(20,5) should return true
3. hasLessPrimeFactor(20,7) should return false
4. **The answer should be valid for any given input.**(above mentioned not passed test case)

What I've done so far :

```
function hasLessPrimeFactor(num,primenum){
    let arr = [];

     if(num < 2 || primenum < 2 || isNaN(num) ||isNaN(primenum)){
    return 0;  
  }

    for (i = 2; i <= num; i++) {
        while ((num % i) === 0) {
            arr.push(i);
            num /= i;
        }
    }

  for (var k = 0; k < arr.length; k++) {
  if(arr[k] == primenum && arr.length <= primenum)
    return true;
    }
    return false;
}

hasLessPrimeFactor(20,5);
```

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the requirements. For `hasLessPrimeFactor(20,7)`, the prime factors of `20` are still 2, 2, and 5, which are all less than 7, so shouldn't the result be `true`? I'm not sure you've described the requirements quite right.

Comment: @JLRishe Sorry,I wanted mention that `hasLessPrimeFactor(20,7)`  given prime number ("7") also want to be a prime factor of the given positive integer("20").

Answer (score 0):

Given the requirement gleaned from your comment that the `primenum` variable should be a factor of `num`, you could verify that at the beginning.  It seems a strange requirement, though-- not really implied in the name of the method, so I'd look closely to make sure you didn't introduce any accidental assumptions.  That said, this would test to ensure the `primenum` parameter is a factor of `num`.

```
if (num % primenum) return false;
```

Additionally, your first for loop need not iterate from `2..num`; it would be sufficient to iterate from `2..primenum`.